# Zurb foundation for sites v6 tabs not working

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb foundation for sites v6 in my project. I am having a page with tabs where I create tabs and tabs content dynamically.

```
<div class="row woocommerce-tabs">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="product-description-tabs">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <li class="tabs-title">
                    <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="product-description-tabs">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                    <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am initiating foundation like so:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

But the problem is that when tabs are created and I want to open some tab, when I have for example two tabs, it just adds the content from the newly opened second tab to the first tab's content. There are no errors in the console, and I am not sure why is it doing that?
I am using also foundation off-canvas on the same page and that works completely fine, it is just the tabs that are not working as expected.

Comment: can you provide website link?

Comment: I have it locally set up

Comment: Provide more info then or learn how to ask questions  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I usually find when Foundation things like tabs don't work it's because I'm not pulling all the js plugins needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess (I'm not that hot on PHP) that as the tab content is being added dynamically, `$(document).foundation();` is running before the tabs themselves have been created (as it will run when the page is first loaded). If my assumption is correct then you can either:

**Reinitialise (if you are updating an existing set of tabs with new content):**

```
Foundation.reInit('tabs'); // generally for all .tabs
```

OR

```
Foundation.reInit($('#product-description-tabs')); // for that one id
```

**Initialise after creation (If this is a new set of tabs)**

```
$('[data-tabs]').foundation(); // Initialise all tabs
```

OR

```
$('#product-description-tabs').foundation(); // Initialise this set of tabs
```

But this must be executed once you have loaded the tabs HTML into the DOM, or it won't actually do anything.